# Getting CORS error from appveyor rest api using angular

Tags: angularjs, cors, appveyor

I'm writing an angular app that makes a GET request via $http service to [AppVeyor REST API](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/api) to get my project [last build status](http://www.appveyor.com/docs/api/projects-builds#get-project-last-build) and I'm getting a CORS error.

When I try from [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) it works.

```
var buildStatus= 'https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/accountName/projectSlug';
var token = 'q3245dsfg'; // my account api token

$http.get(buildStatus, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
 }).then(...
```

This is the error I'm getting on Firefox:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/accountName/projectSlug. (Reason: CORS request failed).`

Any ideas?

Comment: fiddler isn't subject to CORS restrictions but browsers are. If API doesn't have CORS enabled you will need to use a proxy since headers can't be sent for jsonp requests

Comment: Can't give a full answer as this is from my phone. The cors error is as expected. You are making a cross origin request from your browser (angular client). You can read up on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ to understand the issue and than either use json-p hack if only get is required (not advised, bad practice) or if the receiving end is configured for you as requester make a proper cors call using $http (possibly withCredentials). Finally if the receiving end is not configured to whitefish your app you have to make the request from a server-side component.

Comment: Yeah, I know what CORS is. My problem is with AppVeyor REST API

Comment: If I check their website it seems you will have to setup a server-side method to make the call and proxy this to your angular application. E.g. a nodejs server which you expose with a route in your angular app. The nodejs server makes the call and forwards the response back to your angular client.

Comment: I'm making the call to AppVeyor from my node.js server and forwarding the response back to my angular-client as bastijin suggested. But must exist a way of make it from angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the request from my Node.js server to AppVeyor and forwarding the response back to my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Your request failed due to browser security CORS limitations.

For example your page loaded from domain xyz.com. For security reasons browser allow ajax requests from loaded page only for domain xyz.com. 
If your page send ajax request to domain ci.appveyor.com, outer domain must return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with your site domain (or wildcard) as value.

As I understood You cannot change CORS header on remote server so you have another capabilities - you could use server side proxy:

1 - You could use some proxy servers (nginx for example)
2 - You could request data from your business logic and your logic could request data from outer service.

Comment: what on earth does `request data from your business logic` mean?

Comment: We have xyz.com server, on this server we have additional web-service (java, c#, php, whatever... based). Page loaded from xyz.com. JS on page send AJAX request for additional web-service on xyz.com, during this request processing web-service will request data from ci.appveyor.com and return it as response on page.

Comment: don't see any difference than #1 using a proxy on your own server